# Powershell copy script works on my desktop, and the server, but not in SQL Agent

Tags: powershell, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I am attempting to copy database backups from our Prod server to our BCP server.
The following script runs successfully on my desktop and on the server, in PowerShell ISE, running as the same account set in the Run As field in the properties of the SQL Agent job.

When I attempt to run this through a SQL Agent job however, it fails.

**Version 1**

$backuppath = "\\ProdServer\Prod_Backups\msdb\FULL"
$destpath = "\\BCPServer\Prod_Backups\"
Get-ChildItem -path $backuppath |
 sort-object -Property $_.CreationTime |
 select-object -last 1 |
 Copy-Item -Destination $destpath

**Version 1 error:**

> The job script encountered the following errors. These errors did not stop the script:
>   A job step received an error at line 5 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'Get-ChildItem -path $backuppath |
>   '. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Cannot find path '\ProdServer\Prod_Backups\msdb\FULL' because it does not exist.

**Version 2**

$backuppath = "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\ProdServer\Prod_Backups\msdb\FULL"
$destpath = "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\BCPServer\Prod_Backups\"
Get-ChildItem -path $backuppath |
 sort-object -Property $_.CreationTime |
 select-object -last 1 |
 Copy-Item -Destination $destpath

**Version 2 error:**

> A job step received an error at line 5 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'Get-ChildItem -path $backuppath |
>   '. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Invalid Path: 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\BCPServer\Prod_Backups\'.

Comment: @vonPryz, you mean an Admin share?  The two shares are on different servers.